# Disparar um JavaScript na ABA Console no Internet Explorer (F12) Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, internet-explorer

Por favor, estou tentando tornar visível uma combobox dentro de uma página.

Estou usando o Internet Explorer com "F12" (Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor) ABA "Console" disparando o comando na linha de comando embaixo.

Para essa Combobox ficar visível é preciso que outra Combo tenha um valor Específico.

Exemplo: "Conta Corrente"

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-combobox ui-required mode-edit" id="cd_liquid" style="left: 144px; top: 156px;" data-widget="combobox" data-block="COT_MOVIM_ED" data-member="CD_LIQUIDA" data-action="selectionChanged" data-name="cd_liquid">
    <select name="cd_liquid" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="#cd_liquid" style="width: 184px; height: 16px; display: none;">
        <option value="CE">Conta Estrangeira</option>
        <option value="CC">Conta Corrente</option>
        <option value="CP">Conta Poupança</option>
    </select>
    <input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" id="pdcme_liquid" style="width: 168px; height: 16px;" type="text" value="" />
    <button tabIndex="-1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 168px; width: 16px; height: 16px;" type="button">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
    </button>
    <label style="left: auto; width: 141px; right: 0px;" for="pdcme_liquid">Forma Liquidação</label>
</div>
```

Estou tentando fazer assim:

1º) ISSO FUNCIONA -> A ".val" coloca dentro da combo o valor 'Conta Corrente', dessa forma:

```
 $('#pdcme_liquid').val('Conta Corrente')
```

2º) PROBLEMA É AQUI -> Com o valor já colocado dentro, agora preciso que o Javascript "entenda" isso e dispare um evento para tornar visível a outra ComboBox. Já tentei isso:

```
$('#pdcme_liquid').change()
$('#pdcme_liquid').click()
$('#pdcme_liquid').contextmenu()
$('#pdcme_liquid').focus()
$('#pdcme_liquid').focusin() 
$('#pdcme_liquid').focusout() 
$('#pdcme_liquid').keydown()
$('#pdcme_liquid').keypress()
$('#pdcme_liquid').keyup()
$('#pdcme_liquid').load()
$('#pdcme_liquid').mousedown()
$('#pdcme_liquid').mouseenter()
$('#pdcme_liquid').ready()
$('#pdcme_liquid').select()
$('#pdcme_liquid').submit()
$('#pdcme_liquid').trigger()
$('#pdcme_liquid').triggerHandler()
```

Estou tentando no objeto INPUT, Mas não sei se devo disparar um evento no SELECT ou no BUTTON?!?

OU devo selecionar o valor do item "CC" da select e depois disparar um evento para que o javascript interno mostre oa próxima combobox?!?

Comment: Poste todo o código por favor, o seu HTML está faltando MUITA coisa, não tem tag devidamente fechada e isso tudo está dando erros nos testes. Por favor, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/429646/edit) o seu post e poste o restante do código.

Comment: #Jakson_Fischer, okay, corrigido.

Comment: Uma coisa... Eu coloquei o seu código no fiddle pra fazer os testes, quando ele inicia, está iniciando com uma caixa de texto apenas. Você não deveria iniciar o seu combo com o select? Veja como está iniciando: [Exemplo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaksonfischer/ykgxcnb6/4/)

Comment: #Jakson_Fischer, que site interessante o fiddle, não conhecia. Mas o fiddle não reconheceu a DIV como uma Combobox... será que faltou o JSON 1,7 ou algo assim?!?

Comment: Você utiliza algum `CSS` ou `JS` no seu `header`? Caso sim, coloque na sua pergunta este header também que eu coloco no Fiddle, assim ele irá reconhecer

Comment: #Jakson_Fischer, tem algum lugar que tem um tutorial sobre o "jsfiddle.net", estou tentando criar minha conta, mas nem isso estou conseguindo! KKKKK!

Comment: Crie neste [link](https://jsfiddle.net/user/signup/)

Comment: #Jakson_Fischer, deve ter muitos JS, mas infelizmente não tenho acesso ao código fonte. Eu preciso fazer um disparo de evento para trabalhar dentro de um Web Crawler (Web Scraping) a partir de um Windows Form com GeckoFX que estou desenvolvendo. Atualmente estou usando "mouse_event" e "SendKey" ... isso 'trava' o mouse para o usuário, a máquina fica indisponível para o usuário para usar outras aplicações (ao mesmo tempo).

Comment: #Jakson_Fischer, obrigado pelo link.

Comment: Compreendo... Infelizmente creio que não conseguirei te ajudar, mas estou atrás de alguma solução, caso encontre, te aviso

Comment: Já tentou assim: `$('#pdcme_liquid').val('Conta Corrente').change()`? Mas é preciso que na página exista o código para escutar o evento change: `$('#pdcme_liquid').change(function(){
   $("#cd_liquid").show();
});`... só que você está usando dois id's iguais na div e no input, sendo que no input está incorreto o id: `id="#cd_liquid"`... o id não pode começar com `# `...

Comment: Valew #Jakson_Fischer!

Comment: @Sam, o ".val" atribui o valor, mas o ".change" não faz efeito...

Comment: Só vai fazer efeito se na página tiver o código que falei acima e se corrigir os id's mencionados.

Comment: #Sam, então... esse é meu dilema, pois NÃO tenho acesso ao código fonte HTML. Estou fazendo Web Crawler (Web Scraping) para programar um Windows Form com GeckoFX...

Comment: Então vc tem que executar tudo no console: `$('#pdcme_liquid').change(function(){
   $("[name=cd_liquid]").show();
}).val('Conta Corrente').change()`

Comment: #Sam, incrível que o ".val(" funciona, mas não dispara o Javascript oculto que coloca a próxima "combobox" como "visible"...

Comment: Aqui funcionou tranquilo.